# 404 Error with SugarCRM REST API Export

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

The SugarCRM REST API Docs suggest that a request can made to export a particular module to CSV using a GET Request:

> "GET //export export Returns a record set in CSV format along with HTTP headers to indicate content type."

However, when I try this - e.g. with */Accounts/export* I get a 404 error and the following response:

```
{
  "error":"not_found",
  "error_message":"Could not find record: export in module: Accounts"
}
```

It is v10 of the API and my other work so far with it so far has worked OK.

Can anybody help with this?

**Specifically, if I have a custom module name XXXX, what would the REST request have to look like to export this (i.e. download/extract all entries)?**

Answer (score 1):

*rest/v10/Accounts/export* would result in retrieving an Account with the ID "export". 
*rest/v10/Accounts/export/your_id_here* on the other hand might be what you are looking for :-)

Their documentation at rest/v10/help is also very useful

Comment: Hi ogge7 - Thanks for your answer. I have been referring to the rest/v10 docs but to me the documentation for export does not suggest it takes a /your_id_here parameter - it states 'GET /<module>/export' and has three optional JSON parameters. Can you tell me where you are seeing this id documented as being needed and what the ID would be of?

Comment: I'm able to find this at the help-site at rest/v10/help, under GET /<module>/export/:record_list_id . The ID would be the ID of the record you want to export.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure how to use the //export REST API end point but I realised I can export custom modules simply using:

```
http://BASE_URL/rest/v10/CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME?max_num=100&offset=0
```